# System.getProperty("user.dir") return " /"

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a project with selenium,Program can't find `chromedrive.exe` in path. It doesn't seem to exist.

Error is

> "The driver executable does not exist: /C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\chromedriver.exe".

There is " /" front of path this is the problem

I've tried all different syntax of path

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe" );
```

I expect chromedriver exist in `C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe`,
but the error is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\chromedriver.exe

Answer (score -2):

Use this: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\chromedriver.exe");

Comment: Sama error again,My actual problem is what is " /" before path and shows where

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Path of chromedriverand also change '\\' instead of '\');

Comment: Now, you say same thing,I said you ı try with \\ and \ it doesnt matter .Real problem is what is the " /" before in the exception